# Retrieve my balances

Tags: mining-pools, electrum, bitcoin-core-accounts, guiminer

I just recently discovered that i had a GUIminer that i installed in 2012.  I also had Bitcoin Core with several wallet.dat files.  I have been unsuccessful in running a full node as my computer and connection are slow.  Two of the wallets i cant dumpwallet because the passphrase is incorrect.   I was able to dumpwallet one of them and there are 25k+ addresses.  Most Change=1, Script=1 all with the private keys.  I uploaded the master key and have checked many addresses but the all say zero.  I have a watch only address with 18btc that i cannot unlock.

Ive tried pywallet for andriod but run into bin/sh error
In python.  Ive tried it all.   Really need some help finding these balances.

Comment: I think more information is needed to help. By "uploaded the master key" do you mean you imported a HD master key to the wallet? A watch only address could have come from another wallet so that can be tough unless you think that the watch only address is part of the 25k+ addresses then all you would need is to find the corresponding private key out of the 25k key pairs.

Comment: Yes i imported Master to Electrum.  The watch may or may not be from it.  I had the address in a notepad.  All the addresses start with 3, while the $ address is a 1.  Is it possible more btc sits on these addresses but have not been confirmed?

Comment: There was no concept of "master keys" in 2012.

Comment: Like i said..   I had 3 wallet.dat files.  Not sure which one this was.. But it was last used nov 2012 according to my computer.  I believe this is the wallet from the GUIminer and bitcoinqt